# Online Hacking not working

Tags: watch-dogs

I already unlocked online hacking, that is not the problem. But when I am in an active online hacking session, I can not hack the other fixer. I see him, he is highlighted in purple and I see his name, I am standing right next to him.

But I can not hack, he is not available for hacking. Also, we both seem to be invincible. Shooting at each other with all we have, both still standing. Does anyone have similar problems? Please advice!

Comment: have you taken out your smartphone (pressing square on Playstation)? The command won't appear without the phone in your hand, I think.

Comment: Yes, my profiler is active. For example, I can hack the radio next to the target to switch the song, I can hack random npcs but not the target fixer.

Comment: Based on your description, I'm led to believe this is a bug. No surprise with how the game is so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common bug. Happened to myself many times too. 
And to others too, for example see

http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/884092-Hacks-Invincibility-Online-Invasion-Derp

or

Comment: This was deleted a couple days ago already.  Please don't re-post it.  At least answer the question.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is an answer to my question and shows me that it is a known bug.